# Making and calling a function

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a skype card set up and working, but the problem is, I want that a button not only sends a message, but does something in a *for loop*. I've read the docs and it says that the output goes to *Value*. So, my question is, can I make a function containing this *for loop* and then putting the name of that function in the *Value* field of the card? All I currently have is `CardAction plButton = new CardAction(){ Value = XX, Type = "imBack", Title = "Activate command." };` On the XX place, I want to make a for loop. Sorry if this is un-professionally written, as I just started using stackoverflow.

Comment: Please add your existing code, because without it this question is very vague (and slightly confusing)

Comment: All I currently have is `CardAction plButton = new CardAction(){
                            Value = XX,
                            Type = "imBack",
                            Title = "Activate command."
                             };`
On the _XX_ place, I want to make a for loop.

Comment: What kind of data can you put in your Value property? I mean what is the type of Value property

Comment: I suggest reading [ask].

Comment: It says _Supplementary parameter for action. Content of this property depends on the ActionType_

Comment: What I mean is, is it a basic type (like int, float, string etc.) or is it a class or struct? Because if you want to put many items into Value, then it needs to be of certain type. Then you can fill your class with whatever data you want and assign class to Value

Comment: It's a string. It says _string CardAction.Value{get;set;}_

Comment: So why don't you just create a string, loop somewhere doing whatever you want with string and then just assign it to Value? Do it in the same function where you have CardAction, but above your CardAction, or show us more code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you are trying to do is to assign a function to a CardAction, so when the action is clicked that function is launched.

That's not supported in C#. You will have to manually call the function once the button is clicked by checking the message posted back by the action (which will be what you put on the Value property)